# imprimir un rectangulo con "-" python

Tags: python, python-2.x, rectangle

tengo el siguiente programa, yo ya hice un intento pero no sale como me lo piden, aca les dejo el enunciado y el resultado esperado

- Realizar un programa que muestre por pantalla un rectángulo formado de altura n y base m, donde n y m son valores enteros ingresados por teclado.

YO HICE LO SIGUIENTE:

```html
m = input()
n = input()
for i in range(n):
  print"|"
  for j in range(m):
    print "-",
```

y me da como resultado si introducen los valores 3,4

```html
 |
 - - - |
 - - - |
 - - - |
 - - -
```

y tendria que quedar asi con esos valores

```html
- - - -
|     |
- - - -
```

Answer (score -2):

hola tal vez sea una solución....................

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola, nose porque pero me falta toda la columna del lado derecho, nose si habra un error o nose porque no me lo devuelve el print. Me podrias ayudar por favor? muchas gracias!

Comment: Debes agregar una explicación del código, te sugiero revisar [answer] para crear preguntas que sean de ayuda a la comunidad. No olvides realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.